# Clase Repositorio Base no asume Propiedad DBset

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Se esta tratando de migrar de entityframework a core una clase Repositorio base
donde se tiene una propiedad que define el dbset asi:

```
protected DbSet dBset
    {
        get
        {
            return Context.Set<TObject>();
        }
    }
```

al implementar el método filter

```
protected IQueryable Filter(Expression<Func<TObject, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return dBset.Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
        // TODO: Control de excepciones
    }
```

arroja error:

> 'DbSet' no contiene una definición para 'Where' y la mejor sobrecarga del método de extensión 'Queryable.Where(IQueryable, Expression>)' 
>   requiere un receptor del tipo 'IQueryable'

no entiendo porque no asume el dBset que definí como propiedad en esta clase
pero cuando coloco la linea con

```
return Context.Set<Tobject>();
```

con esta linea no sale el error, cual es lo que esta pasando?

Comment: Hola, @ger puedes mostrar el código completo de tu clase Repositorio base? No veo de dónde viene `dBset`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analizando implementaciones de ejemplo similares, como ser:

[Generic Repository Pattern implemented in .NET Core with EF Core](https://medium.com/@marekzyla95/generic-repository-pattern-implemented-in-net-core-with-ef-core-c7e088c9c58)

No veo que tengan problema, podrias ver de cambiar, usando algo como esto:

```
protected IEnumerable<TObject> Filter(Func<TObject, bool> predicate)
{
    return Context.Set<TObject>().Where(predicate);
}
```

quitando el `AsQueryable()` y retornar la lista de objeto con la respuesta de su ejecucion

Comment: era si no quitar asQueryable()